# How many variation are there in this sequence of numbers: 1, 2,3,4 : 1,2,3,4 Minus and plus numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

How many variation are there in this sequence of numbers:   1, 2,3,4 : 1,2,3,4 Format 4 left and 4 right -2-3+1+2 (L or S) -3-4+1-1 [Example Pic of a Long +2+3 L+2-1 Using just 2 numbers (upper Red) and 2 right (lower Aqua)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc18P.jpg) 
How many Variation are there Rules: Numbers can be both positive and negative. Numbers must be in sequence. Only A + 1 or - 1 can change the sequence. At least one side must end in a + 1 or -1. No gaps in a sequence but  not all 4 positions need to be filled +1+2    : -4+1-1    is valid.  Also  only a +1 can follow a negative number and only a -1 can follow a positive number changing the sequence.  You may have -1-2+1 (S) or (L) +1+2-1  Try to draw lines between the number in each sequence to make a visual pattern as in the chart example.

and what if there were just 1,2,3 and 1,2,3

Comment: Your rules are opaque. How is $-2-3+1+2$ "in sequence"? How are there "no gaps" in $-4+1-1$?

Comment: A +1  or a -1  can change the sequence   so yes  a  + 2 would follow the +1 in your example.  You would not see  -2 -3 +2     because  only a -4 or a +1 can follow the -3.  Which  has me notice another rule. which is. Only a +1  can follow a Negative number and only a -1  can follow  + number when  changing  the sequence,    all 4  numbers do not need to be filled in  so U do not need a -2  after that -1  the missing 4th number is ignored,   I may not be understanding  the 2nd question,  Thanks You for helping.

Comment: If we were  drawing lings between the numbers   and started at a -4  the line would go up to the +1   and down to the -1  in a an up  arrow shape,

Comment: Sorry, still incomprehensible. Well, let's see whether I understand: the numbers must be chosen from $\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm4$. A number can be chosen more than once. There must be at most four numbers on each side of the colon. If $n>0$, and if there is a number following $n$, it must be $n+1$ or $-1$; if $n<0$, and if there is a number following $n$, it must be $n-1$ or $1$. The last number on at least one side of the colon must be $\pm1$. Is that it? (and, if so, why? why such a bizarre set of rules?)

Comment: Also, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to include @Gerry in it.

Comment: yes  you are the only one to respond and thanks  -   @Gerry,  It would be better for you to see a graphic image  displaying how the sequences are applied, Can I send it to you - where

Comment: Since I added to the rules  if n > 0  you could only have the next number in sequence  -1 -2  and only a +1  can change it  followed by a -1 or a +2

Comment: It would be better if you came up with a clear description, or if you worked out how to include images here (although you might need some number of points to do that, I'm not sure).

Comment: Send me an email  at esmall1@comcast.net   A picture is worth a 1000 texts.

Comment: A comprehensible question on m.se is worth 1,000 emails. And you're still not using @Gerry.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  This sequence is applied to swing patterns in a financial  charting system for day trading. If you would like to see how this is used in real life send an email please. The goal is to know how many patterns can be formed  Thanks for you questions but I am out of answers.  The goal is to know how many patterns there are for I have visually Identified 49 that loose money and hoped to know how big a project this really is.

Comment: The description I wrote a few comments up – does it describe your sequences? If not, can you give me an example that you want that doesn't fit my definition? or an example you don't want that does fit my definition?

Comment: @Gerry As I watch the charts in live market action I have no idea what patterns will form or when so I am trying to at least know how far I have left to go in identifying all of them.  Further discovery will tell me which ones consistently  are profitable.

Comment: You are not answering my question, Edward. Is my definition the same as your, or isn't it?

Comment: -2 -3 1  S -2 -3 -4-----
2    L 1 2 -1-----
1 -1 -2 1 S -1 -2 -3-----
1 -1 1  S -4-----  
2      L 2 -1------ 
2 -1 1  S -1------  
-2 -3 1  S -1----- 
4    L 4 -1----- 
-1 -2 1  S 1-----  
-1 -2 1 -2 S -2 3------ 
-1 2 3  L 1 2 -1----
1 2   L -2 1 -1----
1 -1 1  S -2-----  
-2 -3 1  S -1 -2----

Comment: I give up.${}{}$

Comment: @Gerry   here is a list of losing trade patterns

Comment: @Gerry  it wount let me put them in as a table format so I use ------ to separate   the L   means if was  a buy  the S  a sell

Comment: Still not answering my question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3832569/looking-for-a-formula-to-find-the-number-of-possible-variations-in-this-sequence       Try this version and ask you question again please @Gerry